# Pass build settings from app target to dependency

Tags: ios, xcode, dependencies, share-extension

In my project, I have two apps and one share extension. The share extension should be embedded in both apps, but with slight differences between the apps (different bundle ID and some settings in the `Info.plist`).

Is there a way to tell which app is being build during the build of the extension (so I can change those values accordingly)? Or maybe a way to "pass" build settings from the app target to the extension target during build?

I was already trying to change those `plist` values after the extension has been built and before embedding it into the app, but that messes with code signing...